# Entity Framework handling concurrency

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, concurrency

Scenario:

I have multiple accounts. Every account has a remaining credit. Every account corresponds to multiple users.

I want the RemainingCredit field to correctly reflect the remaining credit (I'm using EF to abstract away the db).

**E.G.** In a scenario where initial credit is **X** and 2 users log in, one spends **A** , and one spends **B**, I want the end sum to be **X-A-B** (order of read/modify/save should be irrelevant).

After reading up I think optimistic concurrency handling is what I'm looking for, as it scales well and this is very important to my scenario.
The end procedure would be something like:

```
ComputeRemainingCredit(Double amountToBeDeducted) {
    Account acc = context.Accounts.Where(condition)
    ComputeRemainingCreditInternal(acc, amountToBeDeducted);
}

ComputeRemainingCreditInternal(Account acc, Double amountToBeDeducted) {
try {
    acc.RemainingCredit = acc.RemainingCredit - amountToBeDeducted;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException  ex) {
    context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWinds, acc);
    //now I need to rerun the operation
    ComputeRemainingCreditInternal(acc, amountToBeDeducted);
}
}
```

1. Is this a correct interpretation/implementation of optimistic concurrency in EF?
2. My end objective is to have the RemainingCredit field up to date. Are there any better solutions than OptimisticConcurrencyException?

Comment: This is the worst use I have ever seen for concurrency. This is not how you do basic maths on a database. Just do a query.

Comment: Care to detail on your remark? If I'm getting it wrong - point out what I'm doing wrong so I can improve. Only stating that I'm wrong doesn't help one bit.

Comment: @mattmanser could you provide an UPDATE example that would be appropriate for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a field in your table that acts as a timestamp, or a version number, and use that for optimistic concurrency checking.

Say that you have a `Version` field. Set that field's `ConcurrencyMode` property to `Fixed`, and then EF will do the optimistic concurrency checking for you and throw an `OptimisticConcurrencyException` when necessary.

The alternative is to do this work yourself -- fetching the current record, verifying the field value against the one in the record you're updating, allowing or disallowing the update accordingly.

**EDIT** See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/20/tip-19-how-to-use-optimistic-concurrency-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

**EDIT** More or less in pseudocode:

```
bool mustRetry = true;
while (mustRetry)
{
    try
    {
        SpendTheMoney(context, parameters);
        mustRetry = false;
    } catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException exc)
    {
        // Do logging if you need, then just swallow the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that I need the Version/RowVersion/Timespamp field for optimistic concurrency check to work. My question regards more the design approach - having a re entering function to compute the remaining amount - will that do? Other options?

Comment: I suppose it would be easiest to just recompute the remaining credit in your `SpendTheMoney()` function.

Comment: By swallowing the exception you mean - call SpendTheMoney with up to date data?

Comment: By swallowing the exception, I mean simply not rethrowing it. The while loop above makes sure that `SpendTheMoney()` is called again in case of an `OptimisticConcurrencyException`.

Comment: all right - missed the while loop on first try. Seems similar to the original code, using a while instead of a callToSelf. Thanks for the example.

Comment: Be sure you handle other exceptions as well and set `mustRetry = true`  - you don't want to end up with an infinite loop

Comment: I'll watch out for other exceptions & infinite loops - thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can show an error message to the user saying that the operation failed because the data was modified, and then show him the current state of the data. The user would then decide to retry the operation if that was his/her intention.

You can find a good article about concurrency in Entity Framework here:

[Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: I can't ask the user as this is a "behind the scenes" operation - it should "almost always" succeed - only when RemainingCredit falls under a certain amount I have to send an "warning email". I've seen the article you are pointing to and read it - my case is a "don't leave it up to the user" scenario